# Need the return value from a function in a different file 1 in a function in file 2 - plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm a newcomer in JS, so please be understandingly.

I've got a script written in ES6. I've to keep a return value called 'formData' and get it into the another file's function and work with it.
The file-structure has to be like this because of reasons ;-)

If you've any questions, just ask.

Comment: Post your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca do like this.

```
// exporting-file.js
export const formData = 'Value to be exported';

// importing-file.js
import { formData } from 'exporting-file';

// Use the value inside your function
function showTheValue() {
    console.log('Imported value: ', formData);
}

showTheValue();
```

Check out ES6 export and import for more export types